# Recursive tree traversal - saving the path taken to each node

Tags: c#, dictionary, recursion

I'm trying to make a recursive function which traverses through a dictionary of numbers, then outputs the traversed path of each node.

The data structure looks something like this:

```
var tree = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>()
{
    {888, new List<int>() {44}},
    { 44, new List<int>() {183, 275, 100, 216}},
    {100, new List<int>() {299, 400}},
    {299, new List<int>() {504}},
    {216, new List<int>() {33}}
};
```

so a tree structure representing the data structure looks like this

```
                 888
                /   \
               44    (many other nodes and subnodes)
           / /  \  \
        183 275 100 216
               /  \    \
              299 400   33
             /
            504
```

and I want to return a list of list which outputs something like this

```
[888, 44, 183]
[888, 44, 275]
[888, 44, 100, 299, 504]
[888, 44, 100, 400]
[888, 44, 216, 33]
```

This is what have so far, which might not be correct. I can successfully get some of the results I want. I think the problem is that it's not removing nodes that have children where all the child nodes have been visited.

```
public List<int[]> FindPaths(int currentNode, Dictionary<int, List<int>> tree, List<int> temp, List<int> visitedNodes)
    {
            if (tree.ContainsKey(currentNode))
            {
                if (!visitedNodes.Contains(currentNode))
                {
                    visitedNodes.Add(currentNode);
                }

                foreach (var node in tree[currentNode])
                {
                    visitedNodes.Add(node);
                    temp.Add(node);
                    // call method again with new values
                    FindPaths(node, tree, temp, visitedNodes);                                            
                }

                // if node has no children left and is not a leaf node
                // do something here?
            }
            else // we have reached a leaf node
            {
                paths.Add(temp.ToArray());
                temp.RemoveAt(temp.Count - 1);
                return paths;
            }
            return paths;
    }
```

calling the function

```
paths = new List<int[]>();
var temp = new List<int>();
var vistedNodes = new List<int>();
var result = FindPaths(888, tree, temp, vistedNodes);
```

Can anyone help me get the output I want? I'd like to get this working recursively if possible

Comment: Your dictionary defines a *directed graph* where integers are the vertices. **Is your graph guaranteed to be acyclic**?

Comment: If it is not, then consider `1 -> {2, 3}, 2 -> { 3 }, 3 -> { 2 }`, we are traversing from 1.  Is the solution you want `{ [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2] }`? Or do you want to reject the second traversal because `3` is already in the first one?

Comment: Also, a suggestion: **Use immutable data types**.  This sort of problem can be solved both more efficiently and more easily if you stop using mutable collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
public List<List<int>> FindPaths(int currentNode, Dictionary<int,List<int>> tree)
{
    List<List<int>> paths = new List<List<int>>();

    if(tree.ContainsKey(currentNode))
    {
        foreach(var node in tree[currentNode])
        {
            var subPaths = FindPaths(node,tree);
            foreach(var subPath in subPaths)
            {
                subPath.Insert(0,currentNode);
                paths.Add(subPath);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        paths.Add(new List<int>(){currentNode});
    }
    return paths;
}
```

Note that this is assuming that you don't have circular paths (A->B->C->A). If the dictionary contains one, you'll be stuck in the loop. If this is a possibility, you must keep track of the visited nodes and avoid reprocessing them.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your approach, this solution is to keep adding the node when visited, collect the list once there is no key present for that node and remove the element at the end of its iteration.

```
void findPaths(int root, Dictionary<int,List<int>> tree,List<List<int>> pathList, List<int> visitedNodes)
{
    visitedNodes.Add(root);
    if(tree.ContainsKey(root))
    {
        foreach(int v in tree[root])
        {
            findPaths(v,tree,pathList,visitedNodes);
            visitedNodes.RemoveAt(visitedNodes.Count - 1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
            pathList.Add(new List<int>(visitedNodes));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved fairly easy using this approach

```
//Just some helper method
public static IEnumerable<TKey[]> GetPaths<TKey, TDictImpl>(this IDictionary<TKey, TDictImpl> dict) where TDictImpl : IEnumerable<TKey>
{
    var watchlist = new List<TKey>();
    var outlist = new List<List<TKey>>();
    GetPaths(dict, dict.Keys.First(), watchlist, outlist, new List<TKey> { dict.Keys.First() });
    return outlist.Select((l) => l.ToArray());
}
private static void GetPaths<TKey, TDictImpl>(this IDictionary<TKey, TDictImpl> dict, TKey parent, List<TKey> watchlist, List<List<TKey>> outlist, List<TKey> current) where TDictImpl : IEnumerable<TKey>
{
    //Try to get our child from the dict
    if (!dict.TryGetValue(parent, out TDictImpl subs))
    {
        //No child found, no further navigation needs to be done
        return;
    }
    foreach (var it in subs)
    {
        //Simple check to make sure we do not end in some endless loop
        if (watchlist.Contains(it))
        {
            throw new FormatException($"The key {it.ToString()} was attempted to be traversed a second time in {parent.ToString()}.");
        }
        else
        {
            watchlist.Add(it);
        }
        //Add everything to our outlist
        var tmp = current.Concat(new TKey[] { it }).ToList();
        outlist.Add(tmp);
        //Proceed with possible childnodes
        GetPaths(dict, it, watchlist, outlist, tmp);
    }
}
```

produces for

```
var tree = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>()
{
    {888, new List<int>() {44}},
    { 44, new List<int>() {183, 275, 100, 216}},
    {100, new List<int>() {299, 400}},
    {299, new List<int>() {504}},
    {216, new List<int>() {33}}
};
var res = Random.GetPaths(tree);
```

Following output

```
[888, 44]
[888, 44, 183]
[888, 44, 275]
[888, 44, 100]
[888, 44, 100, 299]
[888, 44, 100, 299, 504]
[888, 44, 100, 400]
[888, 44, 216]
[888, 44, 216, 33]
```